# Decrypt AES256 on Python vs PHP

Tags: php, python, cryptography, aes

I'm have problems with AES encryption, using PHP to encrypt and Python to decrypt.

For encrypting, I am using this PHP function:

```
function cryptpass($arg1) {

    $k = '61b4c705859f4158d38090c1e38e8fdc4f3d29db007f012766276aa498835cf6';
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
    $cipher = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($arg1,'aes-256-cbc',$k,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv));
    return urlencode(base64_encode('{"cipher":"'.$cipher.'","i":"'.base64_encode($iv).'"}'));
}
```

And I using this Python code to decrypt:

```
def decryptpass(info):
   key = '61b4c705859f4158d38090c1e38e8fdc4f3d29db007f012766276aa498835cf6'
   data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(info))
   iv = base64.b64decode(data.get('i'))
   cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
   return cipher.decrypt(data.get('cipher'))
```

But when running this code, the following error occurs:

> ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

I understand that my key has 64 bytes, but how is PHP encrypt used it? I tried remove last 32 characters from the key, but that is not working.

Comment: `b64deode` Check spelling of this

Comment: Can we please have a sample JSON string that reproduces the problem? We don't all have both languages installed. :-)

Comment: Sample created in a PHP shell, encrypted text `"Hello world!"`, output `eyJjaXBoZXIiOiJCSzNhb2dpSU80SXpoUVQrdllwWk5nPT0iLCJpIjoiOVFsMUhjTERBZnVBTXFvNlR4bEEzdz09In0=` (I removed the URL encoding, since you clearly are working with valid base64 data).

Comment: Are you using the [pycrypto library](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/)? Can you please include your imports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining a 64-character key; that those 64 characters are hex digits is neither here nor there, the `openssl_encrypt()` will not decode the hex characters in any way, it uses those characters verbatim.

But, AES-256 only takes keys with **32** bytes (== 256 bits), not 64, and `openssl_encrypt()` *silently* truncates the key. The PyCrypto `AES.new()` method on the other hand, explicitly tells you that the key is too long, alerting you to your error here, which is that you should probably decode your hex key to bytes first.

You can successfully decrypt messages if you cut the key down to 32 characters in Python, *or* if you convert your key from hex to bytes in both cases:

```php
$k = hex2bin('61b4c705859f4158d38090c1e38e8fdc4f3d29db007f012766276aa498835cf6');
```

```py
key = bytes.fromhex('61b4c705859f4158d38090c1e38e8fdc4f3d29db007f012766276aa498835cf6')
```

I strongly recommend decoding over truncating; 32 hex characters have a lot less entropy (the bytes cover as many possible values as the number of values encodable in 32 hex characters *squared*, 2 to the power 256 vs. 2 to the power 128).

Because `openssl_encrypt()` also *base64 encodes the return value* you need to base64-decode the `cipher` value on the Python side:

```
>>> data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(info))
>>> data
{'cipher': 'Iu9VgH8DdxHdQgnq8o23ew==', 'i': 'Vz+wy5VS6toNHx7MEYl+/A=='}
# base64:   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Finally, `openssl_encrypt()` adds [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS%235_and_PKCS%237) to the encrypted message to make it fit the AES block size (16 bytes), you need to remove that padding again on the Python side, the PyCrypto `AES.decrypt()` method doesn't do this for you:

```
# Decode from hex to create a key 256 bits (32 bytes) long:
key = bytes.fromhex('61b4c705859f4158d38090c1e38e8fdc4f3d29db007f012766276aa498835cf6')
# or, if you don't use hex2bin in PHP, truncate to 32 characters
# key = b'61b4c705859f4158d38090c1e38e8fdc4f3d29db007f012766276aa498835cf6'[:32]


def decryptpass(info):
    data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(info))
    iv = base64.b64decode(data['i'])
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    padded = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(data['cipher']))
    # manual PKCS#7 unpadding
    return padded[:-padded[-1:]].decode()
```

Note, however, that the PyCrypto project has not seen in a new release in *6 years* now, and should not be trusted to be secure anymore. You really want to use the [`cryptography` project](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) here instead:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

key = bytes.fromhex('61b4c705859f4158d38090c1e38e8fdc4f3d29db007f012766276aa498835cf6')

def decrypt_aes_256(key, iv, encrypted):
    decryptor = Cipher(
        algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), default_backend()
    ).decryptor()
    unpadder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()
    decrypted = decryptor.update(encrypted) + decryptor.finalize()
    return unpadder.update(decrypted) + unpadder.finalize()

def decryptpass(info):
    data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(info))
    iv = base64.b64decode(data['i'])
    encrypted = base64.b64decode(data['cipher'])
    return decrypt_aes_256(key, iv, encrypted).decode()
```

Demo, first in PHP:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > function cryptpass($arg1) {
php {     $k = hex2bin('61b4c705859f4158d38090c1e38e8fdc4f3d29db007f012766276aa498835cf6');
php {     $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
php {     $cipher = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($arg1,'aes-256-cbc',$k,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv));
php {     return urlencode(base64_encode('{"cipher":"'.$cipher.'","i":"'.base64_encode($iv).'"}'));
php { }
php > echo cryptpass("Hello, world!");
eyJjaXBoZXIiOiJJdTlWZ0g4RGR4SGRRZ25xOG8yM2V3PT0iLCJpIjoiVnord3k1VlM2dG9OSHg3TUVZbCsvQT09In0%3D
```

then in Python; with the `cryptography` functions defined as above:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> info = unquote("eyJjaXBoZXIiOiJJdTlWZ0g4RGR4SGRRZ25xOG8yM2V3PT0iLCJpIjoiVnord3k1VlM2dG9OSHg3TUVZbCsvQT09In0%3D")
>>> decryptpass(info)
'Hello, world!'
```